# Circular redirect path detected (see 'Redirect Path' section for details) on facebook

Tags: facebook, share, facebook-apps, facebook-sharer

I am using facebook share service which for an app  which is basically hosted in Facebook environment.

So it looks little bit like following.

Facebook App has a Share button on its page. When user clicks on it, it will share a service Url. If you follow the service Url then it will lead you back to the app page.

FB APP(Facebook button) >Service >Facebook App.

Following is the link to facebook Debugger when I did put my service Url in it(I think that will give much more information than me writing an essay here):

```
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fuat0-0.opusonecorp.com%2F%2Fspinzoneservices%2Fapi%2FReceiveShare%3Fshareid%3D51c153affaa2e31348648e59
```

It gives me error  saying "Circular redirect path detected (see 'Redirect Path' section for details) on facebook"

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 2):

Try setting your og:url to https

`<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.facebook.com/devs.contestfactory" />`

The redirect path at the end pretty much explains this

```
original:   http://uat0-0.opusonecorp.com//spinzoneservices/api/ReceiveShare?shareid=51c153affaa2e31348648e59
302:    https://www.facebook.com/devs.contestfactory/app_299132836865501
og:url: http://www.facebook.com/devs.contestfactory
301:    **https://www.facebook.com/devs.contestfactory**
og:url: http://www.facebook.com/devs.contestfactory
Final URL is in bold (this is the URL we tried to extract metadata from).
URLs that are part of the circular redirect path are highlighted.
```